# Change Android dialog title colour

Tags: android

The following picture shows a dialog produced by calling the `show()` method of a `DialogFragment`. I set the title by calling the `getDialog()` method and then calling the `setTitle()` method. I would like to change the colour of the title and the horizontal line below it. How can this be done?

[image: Android dialog]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title text color using the setStyle() method. If you want more control, you can create a custom component. You can refer to the link below-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Hi Ramesh. Thanks for your answer. Yes. I am exploring that option. I am using `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CalendarDialog);` because I am using a title bar but I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use a Custom Dialog, with no title & create own title Bar and horizontal line. 
or try Changing Different theme settings either explicitly for dialog or the activity itself changing attributes in manifest.